# Proof Morse lemma in Arnold's book about ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the following from Arnold's book about ODEs.

- Why do we get $f(x)=x^2 \phi(x)$ by applying Hadamard's Lemma (see below) twice?
  I only get the same, if I first apply it to $f$, i.e. $f(x)=xg(x)$ and the apply it to $x$, i.e. $x=x h(x)$, which seems odd. Then I would get $f(x)=x^2 g(x)h(x)$ and then I would define $\phi(x):=g(x)h(x)$.
- What is the relation $2\phi(0)=f''(0)\neq 0$ supposed mean. I think I get where it comes from, but at what point is it used to conclude that $y=x\sqrt(|\phi(x)|)$
- Why is the proof now done? If $y=x\sqrt(|\phi(x)|)$, then $y^2=x^2 |\phi(x)|$. How is this equal to $f(x)$? What I get is: $y^2=x^2|\phi(x)|=x x   sgn(\phi(x))\phi(x)=sgn(\phi(x))x^2\phi(x)=sgn(\phi(x))f(x)\iff f(x)=\frac{1}{sgn(\phi(x)}y^2=sgn(\phi(x))y^2$.Where does $2\phi(0)=f''(0)\neq 0$ come into play?

Many thanks in advance!

---

[image]

Comment: The question in the second bullet point: To get differentiability of $y$, which is a composition of $\sqrt{x}$ and $\phi$. Note that the $\phi(0)\neq0$ ensures that we are near a point where $\sqrt{x}$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Notice that $g(0)=0$, because from the chain rule $f'(x)=g(x)+xg'(x)$ and $f'(0)=0$, then applying Hadamard's lemma to $g$ shows there exists $h$ such that $g(x)=xh(x)$ and $f(x)=x^2h(x)$.
2. From the chain rule $f''(x)=2h(x)+4xh'(x)+x^2h''(x)$, but $f''(0)\neq 0$, then $2h(0)\neq 0$, it is needed to ensure that $\sqrt{|h|}$ is well-defined and differentiable near the origin.
3. Notice that by construction $f(x)=x^2h(x)=(x\sqrt{|h(x)|})^2$.

Comment: Why do you say $g'(0)=0$? Shouldn't it be $g(0)=0$, because then Hadamard can be applied to $g$? And in bullet point three, why is there no sgn(h)?

Comment: You are right, I should have written $g(0)=0$ and this actually what I proved (this is typo is now fixed). You can put $\operatorname{sgn}(h(0))$ everywhere in 3 instead of absolute values, it will not change a thing, since $h$ has a constant sign in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: do you have an idea why all of that is left out?

Comment: Russian mathematicians trained during the sovietic era are known to write short proofs going straight to the points and several computational details are left to the readers. Nonetheless, all the structure and ideas for the proof are there.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(1) The first use of Hadamard gives $f(x)= x g(x)$ and then a second application gives $g(x)= x \phi(x)$. Thus $f(x)= x^2 \phi(x)$.

(2) The relation $2\phi(0)= f''(0)$ shows that $\phi(x)$ is nonzero at $x=0$  and thus by continuity the function $\phi(x)$ is nonzero in an interval containing $x=0$. Thus $\phi(x)$  has a square root that is *differentiable.*

(3) This is answered by (1) above.